# <Pinescript> Drawing box in different timeframe

Tags: pine-script

I'm drawing boxes on my chart (Timeframe Daily) but I need those boxes plotted on H1 chart. In addition to having them pictured I need to get top and bottom values: This is the code I'm using:

```
217 box fiboL = box.new(na, na, na, na, color.new(color.green, show_fib ? 50 : 100), 2, bgcolor=color.new(color.green, show_fib ? 75 : 100))
218 var float fibo_topL = na
219 var float fibo_botL = na
220 var fibo_topL_D = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", fibo_topL)
221 if new_max and val_ph_H1 > val_ph_H1[1] 
222    box.set_top     (fiboL,   fiboL_61)
223    box.set_bottom  (fiboL,   fiboL_78)
224    box.set_left    (fiboL, bar_index    [piv_len])
225    box.set_right   (fiboL, bar_index + extend_fib)
226    fibo_topL :=  box.get_top   (fiboL)
227    fibo_botL :=  box.get_bottom(fiboL)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use mutable variables (defined as `var`) inside `security()`.
If `fibo_topL` will be passed into `security()`, it will be calculated in scope of other timeframe, i.e on another chart. So it is impossible to change this value inside any scopes than global of the current chart. Also, you wouldn't be able to pass the boxes itself into `security()`. So now you error is that instead of

```
var float fibo_topL = na
```

should be

```
float fibo_topL = na
```